# c# importing DLL function with const char **aString argument

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport

I have a following export from my C++ dll:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
uint64_t aFunction(const char **aString) noexcept
{
    *aString = "Pointer to a string";
    return 123;
}
```

Now, I'd like to use the function in my C# aplplication, but how to properly use the `const char **` argument in C#? I tried the following, but it is not correct:

```
[DllImport("SomeLibrary.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern UInt64 aFunction([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] out string aString);
```

with example usage:

```
string aString;
aFunction(out aString); // crash
Text = aString;
```

Comment: The pinvoke contract is that the caller needs to release the storage for the string.  It will use the equivalent of Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem().  Guaranteed kaboom for a string literal.  If you can't change the C++ code then you need out IntPtr for the parameter type and marshal the string yourself with Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi().  If you do then you'd consider char* with strcpy() on the C++ side and StringBuilder with sufficient capacity on the C# side.

Comment: How do you propose to free this memory for the string? Best off passing in a buffer with a length from C#

Comment: @HansPassant Very valuable answer. Thank you! Yeah, I cannot change the DLL that already exists. The library keeps resources until it is uninitialized with a dedicated function. I didn't know about the Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem() either. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

By changing import argument from string to IntPtr:

```
[DllImport("SomeLibrary.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern UInt64 aFunction(out IntPtr aString);
```

and then by calling:

```
aFunction(out IntPtr aString);
Text = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(aString);
```